# Is ADFS a must-have, when you deploy hybrid exchange server?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, adfs, exchange-hybrid

With AADC implemented in our AD and Office 365, we want to deploy a hybrid Exchange  next, is ADFS a must? Thanks!

Comment: AD FS is not a mandatory requirement. It is only useful if you are attempting to:

- Pass local user credentials through for a single-signon experience
- Restrict access to Office 365 services via IP, group membership, or other attributes via custom AD FS claims rules.

Exchange Hybrid is 100% independent of that.

Answer (score 8):

No ADFS is an option, particularly if you plan on using other, non Microsoft server apps along with Azure AD as the authentication directory.  It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to this blog for details: [Do I really need ADFS?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2017/02/06/do-i-really-need-adfs/)